# display textview step by step after some duration

Tags: android, multithreading, handle

I want to display button or textview step by step after few second once user click on button with tts.
For instance :

A -----> AB-----> ABC---> Image..
a -----> ab-----> abc---> Image..

all have different text view means 4 text view

I have invisible all the elements want to show and set visible during tun time but it is not working as expected and even dont think it is right solution.

```
public void playRow1(View v) {
    mytexts = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3Img);

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int i=0; i < 3; i++){
                    if(i == 0){
                        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3Img);
                        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3Img2);
                        Button btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);


                        ImageView btnImg1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgObjRow1);
                        ImageView btnImg2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPlayNextRow1);

                        btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btn2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btnImg1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        btn3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        tts.speak("a ", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                        btnImg2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        try{
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        }catch(Exception e){

                        }

            }
        }, 2000 * (count + 1));
    }
```

I believe the run method should be in loop but that was not working.... Please help me to provide some solution for displaying text in steps..

thanks in advance.
itin

Comment: Try using a ContDownTimer, and add the characters one by one tou your View text properties

Comment: Actually i have different text views with image at different location.... do u have any idea abt this.. do i need to create a array or something

Comment: Firstly do not use  Thread.sleep(3000);

Second try to use handler for every setVisibility, not only single.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested a (single TextView) solution which works just fine.
It looks like this:

```
    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    final String str = "Some Text";

    final int secs = str.length();
    new CountDownTimer((secs + 1) * 1000, 1000) // Tick length: 1 second
    {
        int sec = 0;

        @Override
        public final void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            txt.setText(txt.getText().toString() + str.charAt(sec));
            sec += 1;
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }.start();
```

This code goes after your setContentView (in your onCreate() method), and assumes your layout having a TextView called `txtTitle`.

Similarly, you can do with any other TextView.

**[UPDATE]**

This is how to do the same, but with 2 TextViews. The second starts "typing" after the first one has finished:

```
    final TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    final TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle2);

    final String str = "Some Text";
    final String str2 = "Another Text";

    //init();

    final int secs = str.length();
    new CountDownTimer((secs + 1) * 1000, 1000)
    {
        int sec = 0;

        @Override
        public final void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
        {
            txt.setText(txt.getText().toString() + str.charAt(sec));
            sec += 1;
        }
        @Override
        public void onFinish()
        {
            final int secs = str2.length();
            // Start the second CountDownTimer
            new CountDownTimer((secs + 1) * 1000, 1000)
            {
                int sec = 0;

                @Override
                public final void onTick(final long millisUntilFinished)
                {
                    txt2.setText(txt2.getText().toString() + str2.charAt(sec));
                    sec += 1;
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish()
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            }.start();
        }
    }.start();
```

You can easily extend the concept to as many TextViews you want, just start the next CountDownTimer in the `onFinish()` method of the previous one.

Comment: Thanks, but this way it will be long chain. Is this the only way we have to do this or can we have some other way?

Comment: You can run it 10x faster, if you use 1/10th second instead of 1 second (i.e.: replace 1000 with 100) in the CountDownTimers. I don't tell you to parallelize the process in a single CountDownTimer, because the string lengths may vary. So, you would see a crash when you try to get a non existing character in a string. OR you might want to add spaces to the right of the shorter strings, so to make them all same-sized as the longest one.

Comment: I think you have misunderstod my comment, as per your code if i have 9 string instead of 2 (str, str2) that you mentioned, do i have to write code in hierarchy 9 time under onFinish?

Comment: Yes, each under the `onFinish()` of the previous one, if you want the "serial" approach. So, when one CountDownTimer has finished, another one is created and starts writing into the other TextView.

Comment: after implementing this is have added tts under onTick method but i have observed that it is repeating text 3 time. why so ? any idea?

Comment: I guess you set the tts **inside** the first `}.start();`. Put it after the last the `}.start();`

Comment: yes i was doing my activity in onTick method now i have doing in onFinish and things are working fine. Thanks for your help..